# Understanding scipy.ndimage.convolve mode = nearest

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I understand the basic mechanism behind `scipy.ndimage.convolve` i.e. that a kernel slides across an array carrying out element wise multiplication of the surrounding values which are then summed up to provide the new value (assuming normalisation of the kernel).

I've been working on my own convolution from scratch + padding, and comparing it to the `scipy.ndimage.convolve (mode = "nearest"`).

I've used `np.pad` to replicate the padding of `scipy`'s padding (`mode="nearest"`) but for some reason I'm still seeing a different in my final output image compared against Scipy.

Is there anything I'm missing from my understanding of convolution or something additional that Scipy might be doing operation wise?

Comment: I suggest adding your implementation so far to get more accurate support.

Comment: I'm not adding my own code as this is for an assignment i.e. want to work out the code for myself instead of just receving the corrected code.

Comment: which values do you see different? The borders? The corners? The center?

Comment: I would suggest subtracting the reference implementation from your implementation, and plotting the result with plt.imshow(). This will give you a visual indication if there is a pattern to the change.

Comment: Assuming you're allowed to look at it, I believe [this](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/ndimage/src/ni_support.c#L666) is the code responsible for mapping out-of-bounds coordinates to in-bound coordinates for the nearest mode. So SciPy is not using padding to accomplish this.

Comment: How are you using `np.pad`? It has many options to control the values that are used for padding. This is why seeing your code would help. `np.pad(..., mode = "edge")` should be essentialy what `scipy.ndimage.convolve (..., mode = "nearest")` is doing (though convolve does not actually pad the array but reuses the values at the edges).